# How to setEndDate for daterangepicker bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, daterangepicker

I have using daterangepicker bootstrap.

In my form html include two element: #RangeDate and #DateExport

Code bellow is function initialization daterangepicker:

```
('#RangeDate').daterangepicker({
        startDate: moment().subtract('days', 30),
        endDate: '07/03/2018',
        minDate: '01/01/2012',
        maxDate: '07/03/2018',
        ranges: {
            'This month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment()],
            'Last month': [moment().subtract('month', 1).startOf('month'), moment().subtract('month', 1).endOf('month')],
            'Last 30 days': [moment().subtract('days', 30), moment()],
            'Last 60 days': [moment().subtract('days', 60), moment()],
            'This year': [moment().startOf('year'), moment()]
        },
        opens: 'right',
        buttonClasses: ['btn btn-default'],
        applyClass: 'btn-small btn-primary',
        cancelClass: 'btn-small',
        format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
        separator: ' - ',
        locale: {
            applyLabel: 'Apply',
            fromLabel: 'From',
            toLabel: 'To',
            customRangeLabel: 'Option',
            daysOfWeek: ['Su', 'Mo', 'Tu', 'We', 'Th', 'Fr', 'Sa'],
            monthNames: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
            firstDay: 1
        }
    },
   function (start, end) {
       if ($('#fromDate').length) {
           $('#fromDate').val(start.format('DD/MM/YYYY'));
       }
       if ($('#toDate').length) {
           $('#toDate').val(end.format('DD/MM/YYYY'));
       }
    });
```

Selected input #DateExport function bellow:

```
$('#DateExport').datepicker({
        autoclose: true,
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        onSelect: function (date) {
            //I want set endDate daterangepicker here.
        }
    });
```

I have try the following code

Code 1:

```
$("#RangeDate").daterangepicker('setEndDate', date);
```

Code 2:

```
$('#RangeDate').data('daterangepicker').setEndDate(date);
```

Error $(...).data('daterangepicker') is not function.

Code 3:

```
var picker = $('#RangeDate').data('daterangepicker');
picker.setEndDate(date);
```

and code 4:

```
$('#RangeDate').on('cancel', function (ev, picker) {
    picker.setEndDate(date);
});
```

All code above not working.

Comment: Did you check in console?

Comment: running code 2 in console error: $(...).data('daterangepicker') is not function. All code remain not error in console

Comment: Thanks for all! My resolve is remove element input daterangepicker and add rebuild element new. It working :D

Answer (score 0):

use this

```js
$(function() {
  $('input[name="datetimes"]').daterangepicker({
    timePicker: true,
    startDate: moment().startOf('hour'),
    endDate: moment().startOf('hour').add(32, 'hour'),
    locale: {
      format: 'M/DD hh:mm A'
    }
  });
});
```

and you can change timePicker true or false